# IIS redirect rule to catch a folder only when referred to without a trailing slash

Tags: iis, rewrite

I have a site built in PHP that I need to ruin via ISS and it all works fine except for one tiny detail.

It runs under a sub directory, lets say test.   If I access the site in my browser at "http://domain/"  it works fine.   However if I leave off the trailing slash and access "http://domain" the site produces a 404 error.

Now this may be the site's own internal logic doing this incorrectly but as I didn't build it I don't want to go into that. I thought I could use a web.config redirect rule to fix this issue.   In otherwords, detect when the end of the url is without a trailing slash and then redirect to the equivalent with a trailing slash.  Ie...

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="" />
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/" />
</rule>
```

This almost works but doesn't.   The rule is picked up when I access the domain without a trailing slash but unfortunately it is also triggered when the url is with a trailing slash, So I end up with an infinite redirects error in my browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean to match an empty URL?

Comment: Yes.  The issue is that the match url="" also matches "/" and its only the former scenario I want to match

Comment: When I read your post, I thought you wanted to match `test`.

Comment: no... the test part isn't important, it could be in the root of the domain and I believe the same issue would apply.

Comment: Please clarify your question, then, and explain what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I've rewritten small parts of it to clarify

Answer (score 0):

The root `/` indeed isn't passed to the `url` in the `<match>` rule pattern. However, you can test for it through the `{PATH_INFO}` server variable in a condition:

```xml
<rule name="Add trailing slash">
  <match url="^$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/$" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{PATH_INFO}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```